# Change the icon of default Search View android

Tags: android, searchview

I am facing the problem with default search view icon.I want to change the icon in my application and use custom drawable instead of default.

I am using the xml:

```
 <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/searchView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
                </SearchView>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: you can follow this link for custom search view http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631965/Android-Edit-Text-with-Cross-Icon-x  if you  feel its useful upvote please

Comment: Thanks for the help . But I want searchview like functionality.In start there should be icon and on click edit text should gets expands.This link is not appropriate for my scenario.

Comment: actually i was thinking you were talking about changing the default icon so i refer that link because there you can use your custom icon but now you are talking about Collapsible SearchView . Please check my answer hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

here i am giving the code for searchView used in whatsApp like

**your activity_main.xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
           android:id="@+id/status_text"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**your searchview_in_menu.xml in menu folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"

         android:title="Search"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
         android:showAsAction="always"
         android:actionLayout="@layout/searchview_layout"/>
</menu>
```

**your searchview_layout.xml in layout folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/search_view_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**your MainActivity.java is**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchview_in_menu, menu);
        //find the search view item and inflate it in the menu layout
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        //set a hint on the search view (optional)
        mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));
        //these flags together with the search view layout expand the search view in the landscape mode
        searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        //expand the search view when entering the activity(optional)
        searchItem.expandActionView();
        return true;
    }
```

it will produce result like the following screenshot
[image]

[image]

Hope it will serve your purpose.